# How to add an ActivityIndicator to a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do i add an Activity Indicator to my react native project. The page is taking too long to load and i think its because i have a custom marker from my database. But its a function component and i want to keep it that way, all the tutorial i found works for class component and to be host i dont know how to fix it to a function component.

This is my code:

```
function ExploreScreen() {

  const [region, setRegion] = useState(undefined);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    markers,
    categories: [
    ],
  });

  let mapIndex = 0;
  let mapAnimation = new Animated.Value(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      setRegion({
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.04864195044303443,
        longitudeDelta: 0.040142817690068,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    mapAnimation.addListener(({ value }) => {
      let index = Math.floor(value / CARD_WIDTH + 0.3); // animate 30% away from landing on the next item
      if (index >= state.markers.length) {
        index = state.markers.length - 1;
      }
      if (index <= 0) {
        index = 0;
      }

      clearTimeout(regionTimeout);

      const regionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (mapIndex !== index) {
          mapIndex = index;
          const { coordinate } = state.markers[index];
          _map.current.animateToRegion(
            {
              ...coordinate,
              latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
            },
            350
          );
        }
      }, 10);
    });
  });

  const interpolations = state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
    const inputRange = [
      (index - 1) * CARD_WIDTH,
      index * CARD_WIDTH,
      (index + 1) * CARD_WIDTH,
    ];

    const scale = mapAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [1, 1.5, 1],
      extrapolate: "clamp",
    });

    return { scale };
  });

  const onMarkerPress = (mapEventData) => {
    const markerID = mapEventData._targetInst.return.key;

    let x = markerID * CARD_WIDTH + markerID * 20;
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      x = x - SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET;
    }

    _scrollView.current.scrollTo({ x: x, y: 0, animated: true });
  };

  const _map = React.useRef(null);
  const _scrollView = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <MapView
          ref={_map}
          initialRegion={region}
          style={styles.container}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          showsMyLocationButton={true}
          followsUserLocation={true}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          // customMapStyle={theme.dark ? mapDarkStyle : mapStandardStyle}
        >
                    {state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
            const scaleStyle = {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                },
              ],
            };
            return (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                onPress={(e) => onMarkerPress(e)}
              >
                <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap]}>
                  <Animated.Image
                    source={require("../assets/marker.png")}
                    style={[styles.marker, scaleStyle]}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                  />
                </Animated.View>
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.searchBox}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search "
            placeholderTextColor="#adadad"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            style={{ flex: 1, padding: 0 }}
          />
          <Ionicons name="ios-search" size={22} />
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          height={50}
          style={styles.chipsScrollView}
          contentInset={{
            // iOS only
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 20,
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingRight: Platform.OS === "android" ? 20 : 0,
          }}
        >
          {state.categories.map((category, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.chipsItem}>
              {category.icon}
              <Text>{category.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          ref={_scrollView}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH + 20}
          snapToAlignment="center"
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentInset={{
            top: 0,
            left: SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET,
            bottom: 0,
            right: SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET,
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingHorizontal:
              Platform.OS === "android" ? SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET : 0,
          }}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    x: mapAnimation,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: true }
          )}
        >
          {state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
            <View style={styles.card} key={index}>
              <Image
                source={marker.image}
                style={styles.cardImage}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
              <View style={styles.textContent}>
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardtitle}>
                  {marker.title}
                </Text>
                <StarRating ratings={marker.rating} reviews={marker.reviews} />
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardDescription}>
                  {marker.description}
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {}}
                    style={[
                      styles.signIn,
                      {
                        borderColor: "#0A4415",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                      },
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={[
                        styles.textSign,
                        {
                          color: "#0A4415",
                        },
                      ]}
                    >
                      Get Ticket
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </Screen>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a piece of state that indicates whether user's location is loading or not. Before calling the getCurrentPosition method set isLoading state to true, and once location is fetched, in callback function, set that state to false. Below is the code snippet.

```html
const [isLocationFetching, setLocationFetching] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    setLocationFetching(true);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
    setLocationFetching(false);
      setRegion({
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.04864195044303443,
        longitudeDelta: 0.040142817690068,
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

Based on current state return either map view or activity indicator. You can use this library for activity indicator https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-activity.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I got that but now it just keeps loading the Activity Indicator, probably im not doing it right. BTW.. I dont want it to display after the user's location is loaded. I want it to display after the marker is loaded. The marker is from the database. It takes a while to fetch that.

Comment: THis is how i rendered it, maybe something is wrong    `{setLocationFetching ? (
        <View style={[styles.centerElement, { height: 300 }]}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ef5739" />
        </View>
      ) : ( Map Code )}`